# With HTTP/HTTPS communication, which combinations are actually safe?

Tags: http, encryption, https

Let's just make up an example - we are sending and/or receiving a secret value in HTTP header. Let's call it `X-Secret: I wear diapers`.

Now, I'm curious which ways the value is actually encrypted. We have 8 possible combinations:

1. HTTP sends `X-Secret` to HTTP in a request
2. HTTP sends `X-Secret` to HTTPS in a request
3. HTTPS sends `X-Secret` to HTTP in a request
4. HTTPS sends `X-Secret` to HTTPS in a request
5. HTTP receives `X-Secret` from HTTP in a response
6. HTTP receives `X-Secret` from HTTPS in a response
7. HTTPS receives `X-Secret` from HTTP in a response
8. HTTPS receives `X-Secret` from HTTPS in a response

Which combinations will have `X-Secret` value encrypted and safe?

Comment: You can't mix HTTP and HTTPS in a single request/response pair.

Comment: I don’t think that’s true. You can make requests to HTTPS from your HTTP website just fine. The other way around is blocked by browsers, isn’t it? But not sure about other clients.

Comment: If it wasn’t true, Facebook login API etc. would only work for HTTPS websites and it’s not the case.

Comment: But when an HTML page loaded over HTTP makes an HTTPS request it's still HTTPS to HTTPS.

Comment: This is my question. Can you say which values are safe and which are not?

Comment: A connection is either encrypted or not. If your website loads via HTTP, then that data is not encrypted. If your web page then loads a resource from Facebook in over HTTPS then _that_ connection is encrypted. If you then send information that your web page received from Facebook back to your own server it's not encrypted again. Those are just two separate connections.

Comment: Is request and response done via the same connection or two separate connections?

Comment: Those are on the same connection.

Comment: I’m still trying to understand it better. So who decides if it’s encrypted or not? The requesting one or the receiving one?

Comment: You need to see them completely separate. One connection is between the browsers and your webserver, the other one is between the browser and Facebook. Who decides depends. If you call HTTP then it is not encrypted and the data will be sent to port 80. If you call HTTPS it will be encrypted and the data will be sent to port 443. A server can decide to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS in various ways. So in that case the servers forces you to use HTTPS.

Comment: Do you know some good tutorial explaining this process in detail? I’m also wondering how encryption keys are handled.

Comment: I don't, sorry. I didn't learn it myself in one go either. Learned part of it during my education and part of it in practice.

Comment: Yeah, I always find tutorials missing the essence of it.